# Matrix created from a function, and concatenated column vector of the matrix

Tags: python, numpy, math

We have a function f(x,y). We want to calculate the matrix Bij = f(xi,xj) = f(ih,jh) for 1 <= i,j <= n and h=1/(n+1), such as :

[image]

If f(x,y)=x+y, then Bij = ih+jh and the matrix becomes (here, n=3) :

[image]

I would like to program a function calculating the column vector b that concatenates all the columns of Bij. For example, with my previous example, we would have :

[image]

I done, we can change the function and n, here f(x,y)=x+y :

```
n=3
def f(i,j):
    h=1.0/(n+1)
    a=((i+1)*h)+((j+1)*h)
    return a
B = np.fromfunction(f,(n,n))
print(B)
```

But I don't know how to do the vector b. And with

```
np.concatenate((B[:,0],B[:,1],B[:,2],B[:,3])
```

I get a line vector, and not a column vector. Could you help me ? Sorry for my bad english, and I'm beginner in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ravel` function along with a new axis should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0.5, 0.75, 1],
              [0.75, 1, 1.25],
              [1, 1.25, 1.5]])
x.T.ravel()[:, np.newaxis]
# array([[ 0.5 ],
#        [ 0.75],
#        [ 1.  ],
#        [ 0.75],
#        [ 1.  ],
#        [ 1.25],
#        [ 1.  ],
#        [ 1.25],
#        [ 1.5 ]])
```

Ravel stitches together all the rows, so we first transpose the matrix (with `.T`). The result is a row-vector, and we change it to a column vector by adding a new axis.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# create sample matrix `m`
m = np.matrix([[0.5, 0.75, 1], [0.75, 1, 1.25], [1, 1.25, 1.5]])

# convert matrix `m` to a 'flat' matrix
m_flat = m.flatten()    
print(m_flat)

# `m_flat` is still a matrix, in case you need an array:
m_flat_arr = np.squeeze(np.asarray(m_flat))
print(m_flat_arr)
```

The snippet uses [`.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), [`.asarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) and [`.squeeze()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to convert the original matrix `m` being

```
matrix([[ 0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ],
        [ 0.75,  1.  ,  1.25],
        [ 1.  ,  1.25,  1.5 ]])
```

into an array `m_flat_arr` of:

```
array([ 0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ,  0.75,  1.  ,  1.25,  1.  ,  1.25,  1.5 ])
```